# awk command for mapping columns & join them

Tags: awk

cat file.txt

1;2|56;2

1|67

1|56

2;1;1;1|56;56;56;56

I have above as input & i want to show it as, read till pipe & join will be like
1st column on left side of pipe will be joined with 1st column on right side of pipe,
so the expected output will be

1-56

2-2

This is for 1st row only. for all rows same way it should happen.
your help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
awk -F'[;|]' '{for(i=1; i<=NF/2; i++) print $i "-" $(i+NF/2)}'  file

1-56
2-2
1-67
1-56
2-56
1-56
1-56
1-56
```

explanation:
This approach takes into account the the pipe symbol is always in the middle:

```
awk -F'[;|]' '               # Use the semicolon and the pipe symbol as field separator
  {
    for(i=1; i<=NF/2; i++)   # For every field on the left hand side of the pipe symbol
      print $i "-" $(i+NF/2) # Print each field on the left hand side (LHS) of the 
  }                          # pipe symbol together with its RHS counterpart 
'  file
```

Comment: thanks very much. Can you please explain the command, how it is written

Answer (score 0):

`awk` to the rescue!

```
awk -F\| '{n=split($1,a,";");
           m=split($2,b,";"); 
           min=n<m?n:m; 
           for(i=1;i<=min;i++) print a[i]"-"b[i]}' file

1-56
2-2
1-67
1-56
2-56
1-56
1-56
1-56
```

perhaps you want to put a separator between the the output lines to indicate records...